# Can we run Junit5 cases with Jmockit using @ExtendWith annotation?

Tags: jmockit, eclipse-mars, junit5

I have run JUnit 5 cases with JMockit using `@RunWith` annotation but I need to remove support of JUnit 4.12 so is there any alternatives to do so?

Comment: JMockit supports JUnit 5 out-of-the-box since version 1.26, back in July 2016.

Comment: can we do it in eclipse-mars without using @RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)?

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a) is the first version with native JUnit5 support. Upgrade and you will not need @RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)